# Quicksort with insertion Sort finish - where am I going wrong?

Tags: java, performance, sorting, overflow

I am working on a project for a class. We are to write a quick-sort that transitions to a insertion sort at the specified value. Thats no problem, where I am now having difficulty is figuring out why I am not getting the performance I expect.

One of the requirements is that it must sort an array of 5,00,000 ints in under 1,300 ms (this is on standard machines, so CPU speed is not an issue). First of all, I can't get it to work on 5,000,000 because of a stack overflow error (too many recursive calls...). If I increase the heap size, I am still getting a lot slower than that.

Below is the code. Any hints anyone?

Thanks in advance

```
public class MyQuickSort {

    public static void sort(int [] toSort, int moveToInsertion)
    {
        sort(toSort, 0, toSort.length - 1, moveToInsertion);
    }

    private static void sort(int[] toSort, int first, int last, int moveToInsertion)
    {
        if (first < last)
        {
            if ((last - first) < moveToInsertion)
            {
                insertionSort(toSort, first, last);
            }
            else
            {
                int split = quickHelper(toSort, first, last);
                sort(toSort, first, split - 1, moveToInsertion);
                sort(toSort, split + 1, last, moveToInsertion);
            }
        }
    }

    private static int quickHelper(int[] toSort, int first, int last)
    {
        sortPivot(toSort, first, last);
        swap(toSort, first, first + (last - first)/2);
        int left = first;
        int right = last;
        int pivotVal = toSort[first];
        do
        {
            while ( (left < last) && (toSort[left] <= pivotVal)) 
            {
                left++;
            }

            while (toSort[right] > pivotVal) 
            {
                right--;
            }

            if (left < right) 
            { 
                swap(toSort, left, right); 
            }

        } while (left < right);

        swap(toSort, first, right);


        return right;
    }

    private static void sortPivot(int[] toSort, int first, int last)
    {
        int middle = first + (last - first)/2;

        if (toSort[middle] < toSort[first]) swap(toSort, first, middle);

        if (toSort[last] < toSort[middle]) swap(toSort, middle, last);

        if (toSort[middle] < toSort[first]) swap(toSort, first, middle);

    }

    private static void insertionSort(int [] toSort, int first, int last)
    {
         for (int nextVal = first + 1; nextVal <= last; nextVal++)
            {
                int toInsert = toSort[nextVal];
                int j = nextVal - 1;
                while (j >= 0 && toInsert < toSort[j])
                {
                    toSort[j + 1] = toSort[j];
                    j--;
                }
                toSort[j + 1] = toInsert;
            }
    }

    private static void swap(int[] toSort, int i, int j)
    {
        int temp = toSort[i];
        toSort[i] = toSort[j];
        toSort[j] = temp;
    }

}
```

Comment: What class is this? highschool/college? I'm curious

Comment: College, 2nd year, so I don't imagine its anything TO complex... I think I may just have a small error...

Comment: Just had a look into the Java implementation, they fall back to insertionsort when the number of elements becomes less than 7. http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Arrays.java.html

Comment: the size of the subarray where we move to an insertion sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Actually, not my sorts fault at all. I was generating numbers between the range of 0-100 (for testing to make sure it was sorted). This resulted in tons of duplicates, which meant way to many partitions. Changing the range to min_int and max_int made it go a lot quicker.

Thanks for your help though :D

Comment: Yes, this is another pitfall to watch out for in quicksort. You can use Bentley-McIlroy partitioning (google it) to be able to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this with your algorithm, and I don't know what kind of data set you're running with, but consider choosing a better pivot than the leftmost element.  From Wikipedia on Quicksort:

> Choice of pivot In very early versions
>   of quicksort, the leftmost element of
>   the partition would often be chosen as
>   the pivot element. Unfortunately, this
>   causes worst-case behavior on already
>   sorted arrays, which is a rather
>   common use-case. The problem was
>   easily solved by choosing either a
>   random index for the pivot, choosing
>   the middle index of the partition or
>   (especially for longer partitions)
>   choosing the median of the first,
>   middle and last element of the
>   partition for the pivot

Comment: if you take a closer look at my code, you will see that I look for the median of the first, middle, and last (under the sortPivot). I move that into the first position and then use that as my pivot (funny way of doing it I know, it was just quicker :P)

Comment: Why do you go through all of those hoops?  Why not just pick the value in the middle of the array?  The call to the method that does the swap is unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

When the input array is large, its natural to expect that recursive functions run into stack overflow issues. which is what is happening here when you try with the above code. I would recommend you to write iterative Quicksort using your own stack. It should be fast because there is no stack frame allocations/deallocations done at run time. You won't run into stack overflow issues also. Performance also depends on at what point you are running insertion sort. I don't have a particular input size where insertion sort performs badly compared to quicksort. I would suggest you to try with different sizes and I'm sure you will notice difference.

You might also want to use binary search in insertion sort to improve performance. I don't know how much it improves when you run on smaller input but its a nice trick to play.

I don't want to share code because that doesn't make you learn how to convert recursive quicksort to iterative one. If you have problems in converting to iterative one let me know.

Comment: @Srikanth - converting from recursive to iterative will not help this person.  Large data sets will just generate an OutOfMemoryError instead.

Comment: a binary insertion sort here is a bad idea... binary insertion sort is only faster on arrays > 100 elements than standard insertion sort (numbers may differ), but here insertion sort is used to speed up things when the number of elements becomes less than, say 10-12.

Comment: @Amir: Of Course any given solution can run into OutOfMemoryError if the input is sufficiently large. Converting from recursive to iterative increases the input size that can be handled by the program. The space occupied by function cal stack is obviously more than the stack used in iterative version. That means if recursive version can handle input size of n, iterative version with the same memory can handle input bigger than n. I can't say any upper bound on it without knowing exact space usage by function call stack. I do not consider 5,00,000 ints as *Large data set*.

Comment: @Helper: I agree with you. You have the numbers. I gave a general idea of binary search effect on performance here. I never said it improves performance for small input. OP has not mentioned at what size insertion sort is used. OP can play around with different values of it and see how it affects. That is interesting task to figure out break even point for when to employ insertion sort. I didn't make any assumption on moveToInsertion value. thats why I suggesting trying out binary search trick. It may not work out for some values. But OP will learn when it performs good or bad.

Comment: @Srikanth: Why would you recommend that this person convert their algorithm from recursive to iterative (hard to do) if the data size he's chosen will require him to set a JVM arg even after your change?  You don't think you'll need to set a larger Xmx value than the default 64m with 5 million ints?  He can just set the -Xss size and *not* convert his algorithm.

Comment: @Amir: though the question is in the context of Java, I answered so far being language-agnostic. All I'm saying is if a recusrsive version can handle input of size N just before running into stack overflow issues, iterative version can handle input bigger than N (can't quantify how big) for sure without running into stack overflow issues. programmer stack uses less memory compared to language stack frames built on function call. I think its not hard to convert it to iterative version. I'll try it out sometime and get some results.